# Enable traps on FIB (Forwarding Table) changes

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, snmp, cisco-commands

I've been working for weeks to enable sending traps for FIB changes on our Cisco 2600 router. I finally found this command is responsible for that:

```
snmp-server enable traps cef peer-fib-state-change
```

But it seemed Cisco 2600 does not accept the `cef` command. After retrieving the whole trap options that can be enabled, we found the following list is all traps which are supported. We found none of them is actually directly enabling FIB changes, however some of them looked relevant, such as entity. Is there any ways to infer FIB changes on any of these options?

```
  atm          Enable SNMP atm traps
  bgp          Enable BGP state change traps
  bstun        Enable SNMP BSTUN traps
  cnpd         Enable NBAR Protocol Discovery traps
  config       Enable SNMP config traps
  config-copy  Enable SNMP config-copy traps
  dial         Enable SNMP dial control traps
  dlsw         Enable SNMP dlsw traps
  dnis         Enable SNMP DNIS traps
  dsp          Enable SNMP dsp traps
  entity       Enable SNMP entity traps
  envmon       Enable SNMP environmental monitor traps
  frame-relay  Enable SNMP frame-relay traps
  hsrp         Enable SNMP HSRP traps
  ipmobile     Enable SNMP ipmobile traps
  ipmulticast  Enable SNMP ipmulticast traps
  ipsec        Enable IPsec traps
  isakmp       Enable ISAKMP traps traps
  isdn         Enable SNMP isdn traps
  msdp         Enable SNMP MSDP traps
  pim          Enable SNMP PIM traps
  pppoe        Enable SNMP pppoe traps
  rsvp         Enable RSVP flow change traps
  rtr          Enable SNMP Response Time Reporter traps
  snmp         Enable SNMP traps
  stun         Enable SNMP STUN traps
  syslog       Enable SNMP syslog traps
  tty          Enable TCP connection traps
  voice        Enable SNMP voice traps
  vtp          Enable SNMP VTP traps
  xgcp         Enable XGCP protocol traps
```

Comment: What software version are you running on your 2600?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CEF-MIB wasn't added to the cisco MIB until iOS relase 12.2(31)SB so you will need that version or higher before you can alert on CEF.

However it doesn't look like CEF-MIB ever made it to the 2600 series platform, at least as of 12.3(6f). I also looked through various iOS images for the 2600 series and could not find CEF-MIB. Needless to say without the needed OIDs present, you will not be able to alert specifically for CEF.

MIB Instance Identifiers for CEF:

- cefResourceFailureNotifEnable.0 -i 1
- cefPeerStateChangeNotifEnable.0 -i 1
- cefPeerFIBStateChangeNotifEnable.0 -i 1
- cefInconsistencyNotifEnable.0 -i 1

You can check for CEF instance identifiers with the following command:

```
Router# show snmp mib | inc cef
```

Sources:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2sb/feature/guide/sbcefmib.html#wp1072297

To find specific MIB information on your device and available images, you can use Cisco's MIB Locator tool to see if CEF-MIB is available.

http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/servlet/index